# Upload file FTP with Filesystem Laravel error

Tags: laravel, ftp, upload

I try to upload a video file to my download server with FTP file system in laravel but I have a this error: 
League\Flysystem\ConnectionRuntimeException: Could not connect to host: myip, port:21 in file /home/test/domains/myhost/laravel/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Ftp.php on line 140

in my filesytem.php

```
 'ftp' => [
            'driver'   => 'ftp',
            'host'     => 'myip',
            'username' => 'myusername',
            'password' => 'mypass',
            'port'     => 21,
        ],
```

how to fix this error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fix this issue by enabling an FTP extension in my server.

Answer (score 0):

FTP port:21 is for pass control information.
Did you try port:20 ?

Answer (score 0):

im using sftp because when i using ftp is error in port too. and don't forget too enable ftp in php.ini

```
'sftp' => [
            'driver' => 'sftp',
            'host' => 'xxx.xxx.com',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'pass',
            'root' => ' xxx' , // for example: /public_html/images
```